# How to actually use OkHTTP

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm trying to understand `okhttp` and I'm falling short because they don't seem to actually show a full example. Could somebody point me to where there is or even give a quick example of a login script. You click the button, than pass the email and password to another class that will use `okhttp` to make the call to me API server.

Comment: why you need to use OkHttp ! you should use Volley . http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html .

Answer (score 0):

Check out okHttp documents. Its easy to use.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Basically you should used it like the following:

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    final Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                         @Override
                         public void onFailure(Request request, finaIOException e){
 }

      @Override
      public void onResponse(final Response response) throws IOException {
}
```

Comment: I've done that. I'm trying to understand if I create a class for example LoginAPI, how would I call it from my activity when I click the sign in button. How I pass the email and password into okhttp, and how I get the results back to my activity. It seems to be a lot different from when I last programmed in android using the Apache http client.

Comment: Hi Bobby, take a look at the callback.